# Why I can't reach stdin at startup on Raspberry-Pi Jessie Lite?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, raspberry-pi2, getchar

I have this code. what I want to do is to wait for user to press 'q' to end the program.

```
.
...starting few threads, which use fflush(stdout) (just saying...)
.
char n = 0;
while (n != 'q') {
    n = getchar(); //tried to use scanf() here as well
    printf("%c", n);
}
...killing all threads...
return 0;
```

When I run this **in a normal Linux enviroment it works fine.**
The problem starts when I run this program at startup on my raspberry-pi with debian jessie lite distribution (I added the path to the program to /etc/rc.local) - it ends in an infinite loop, `scanf` is still returning `-1` and `getchar()` some weird character and the program won't end, when I press `q`. Ctrl+C doesn't work either so there is no way, how to end the program.
Any suggestions? (at least how to kill the program...?)

Edit: To let you know what the program does.
Raspberry-pi with this program is attached to some serial ports and converts and transfers some GPS data. It should work "out of the box" without any keyboard or mouse or monitor. = **Just plug the device to some cables and do nothing more.** In some cases someone would like to see log files on the raspberry, so he needs to stop the program, obviously.

Edit2: when I did the same with some normal Raspbian, it worked fine too.

**Update:**

I tried to debug it - shrinked the code to this only

```
int main(void){
    char n=0;
    int x;
    while (n != 'q'){
        clearerr(stdin);
        x=scanf("%c",&n);
        printf("%c %d\n",n,x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

added `service start udev` to rc.local and tried command `update.rc.d udev enable`

output on raspberry-pi when launched at startup is still

```
-1
-1
-1
.
.
```

so there definitely have to be something wrong with stdin.
After startup and on other systems, the output is obviously `q 1` (when I press 'q' (and enter) ...)

when I tried to read from `/dev/tty`, `fopen()` returned `NULL`

Really need a help with this

Comment: Waiting for user-input in a startup progam is probably not a good idea ...

Comment: At least not one that runs from rc.local, running it from inittab could possibly work.

Comment: Need a lot more information to answer this question properly.  Need to see how you're opening your file, variable type for n etc.

Comment: and can you tell me why...? :)

Comment: i just added one line "/path/program" to rc.local, n is normal char

Comment: getchar returns an int. This is no coincidence.

Comment: well, char is basically int and this has nothing to do with my problem ;)

Comment: `char is basically int` not true. `this has nothing to do with my problem` if you have already solved you problem, you might know what has nothing to do with it, otherwise, don't be so sure.

Comment: " .... and the program won't end, when I press `q`".  What do you think should happen if you typed `A` <backspace> `B`.  Do you expect code to receive 1 or 3 `char`?

Comment: Maybe `init` doesn't like the fact there is no keyboard, and closes `stdin`, so no child process gets `stdin`. If you want to read from a serial port, you need to explicitly open a tty associated with that serial port.

Comment: @chux only one. I can see the letters on the screen normally as I type them and I have to press enter to "send" it

Comment: @Charlestone "only one." implies that input is "buffered".   Code does not receive `'q'` when the <Q> key is pressed. It waits.   `scanf()` receives `'q'` after  keys <Q> .... <Enter> are pressed.

Comment: "and I have to press enter to "send" it" ...

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to write this loop is:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'q'){
    putchar(c);
}
```

Your implementation cannot detect end of file and will loop forever, printing funny characters such as `ÿ`.

Comment: ok, but why is EOF on stdin? and why nothing happens when I press 'q'? :/

Comment: I don't know why `stdin` is at end of file, but `scanf` return value of `-1` indicates this.  You must check for this correctly, otherwise you will loop forever as your input never reaches the program.

Comment: but how can I stop the program then? If I stoped it after EOF on stdin, It wouldn't start at all because there is always EOF on stdin, even if I call clearerr()

Comment: @Charlestone: if `stdin` is at end of file, it must be redirected from an empty file, you cannot get your input from that.  How do you run your program?  Do you use an IDE, do you have a terminal?

Comment: Please re-read the question, I've updated it several times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess that stdin maybe redirected to something else and you need to read from keyboard directly. try the following code:

```
FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");
if (!tty) {
    exit(1);
}
int n=0;
while (n != 'q'){
    n=fgetc(tty); //tried to use scanf() here as well
    printf("%c",(char)n);
}
```

Comment: `n` should be defined as `int` and your should check for `EOF` in the `while` loop.  Also fix the typo on `printf`.

Comment: welll, this might be the problem! /dev/tty can't be opened at startup - fopen returns null. Any Ideas where else the keyboard could be? :)

Comment: @Charlestone /dev folder may not be populated in the time you executing your program at startup. generally udev program is responsible for that. my suggestion is to  put your program start time after udev execution

Comment: I tried to put `service udev start` to rc.local, iand i also tried `update.rc.d udev enable` command. Nothing worked. Any other suggestion how to achieve what you have suggested? :) (btw other tty (like ttyUSB1) work fine, and I can see what I typed on the screen...)

Comment: @Charlestone: you mean the program worked with "/dev/ttyUSB1"?

Comment: no, I mean that I am able to read some data from GPS reciever which is connected to /dev/ttyUSB1 :)

Comment: @Charlestone: can you check if the code works in normal linux mode (not startup)? I want to make sure that keyboard mounts under /dev/tty not something else

Comment: Why `(char)` in `printf("%c",(char)n);`?  Should code not look for `n == EOF` before `printf()`?

Comment: @chux because the printf is there just for debugging :)